# Sharing folder error

Tags: file-sharing

I have 10 user on my ubuntu 10.04 - one folder called "public" located in one user's documents.

I like to share the folder, so everyone have access to that folder, as it will be the local folder everyone will use.

Under sharing, I get the following error message:

'net usershare' returned error 255: net usershare add: cannot convert name "Everyone" to a SID. Invalid parameter."

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to share the folder between all the *local* users on a single machine, yes? In that case, you do not need to involve sharing, because that is for sharing over a local network. Everything you need to do is to modify the permissions of the folder such that anyone can read and write in that folder. For example, you can set

```
chmod a+rwx folder
```

anyone will be able to read, write and delete files within that folder. If you set

```
chmod a+rwxt folder
```

then anyone will be able to read and write, but only the person who created a file or directory will be allowed to remove it.

The above command is for command line, but you can also set the permissions using the graphical user interface; right-click on a folder, select properties -> permissions.

Comment: Yes, doing this the way by the graphical interface, I get the error above, I am unable to change the permissions. 

I have recreated the folder, and I was allowed to change the permissions, but still have some problems with the created new document in side the folder that is shared....

Hope you understand